# how to target and delete one row from a table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove one specific row from the list in tbody after clicking on the delete button. Could you help me figure out how to make it work with plain javascript?
I always get the error message "cannot get / a".

```
function updateUI() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('entry-table');

    for (var i = 0; i < Storedcontact.length; i++) {
        var entry = Storedcontact[i];      

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.innerHTML = `
        <td>${entry.name}</td>
        <td>${entry.surname}</td>
        <td>${entry.phone}</td>
        <td>${entry.email}</td>
        <td><a href="a" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="a" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit">Edit</a></td>
        `;

        tbody.appendChild(row);


function clearFields() {
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("surname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  }

  clearFields();

    }
}


tbody.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()})

    function removeContact(event) {
        if (event.classList.contains("delete")) {
            event.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't do that, use insertRos, insertCell  => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using inline javascript for this sort of thing, keeps it simple and easy to read.

```
<a href="a" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" onClick="document.getElementById('entry-table').deleteRow(${i});">Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you weren't that far. Here how you can do that:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('table td button'); // the delete buttons
for (let i=0; i < btns.length; i++) { // you can use the modern forEach but this is faster
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // trigger event when hitting each button:
    this.closest('tr').remove(); // remove the line
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>line1 </td> <td> more </td> <td> <button>remove</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>line2 </td> <td> more </td> <td> <button>remove</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>line3 </td> <td> more </td> <td> <button>remove</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>line4 </td> <td> more </td> <td> <button>remove</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>line5 </td> <td> more </td> <td> <button>remove</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

You can read more about remove() on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)
and on [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) too.
Enjoy Code!

Be aware, closest() is [not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=closest). Here's a function that mimics its functionality for your purposes:

```
function closestParent(element, tagName){
    try{
        while(element.tagName != tagName.toUpperCase()) element = element.parentNode;
        return element;
    }
    catch(e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AaronPlocharczyk  thanks for the edit. By the way, IE doesn't support both closest and remove. In production one should use the provided polyfill with the links.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you want to delete them onclick? execute this code after all rows have loaded in the page:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
    trs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.outerHTML = "";
    });
}
```